# Hibernate self-reference entity as non null column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, hibernate-5.x

I'm using Hibernate 5 and Spring 3.2.4.  I'm deigning a User entity in which I want to include a reference to the user that has created the entity - so a self reference.  The self reference itself isn't too problematic, but I want to specify the field as non null.  Is this possible?  How do I create the first entry in the DB if the field is non null as there referenced entity does not already exist?

Ex:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long User.id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private User user;


    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

If I try:

```
User u = new User();
u.setUsername("username");
u.setCreatedBy(u);
```

and try to persist `u`, I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: com.domain.User.createdBy -> com.domain.User
```

I understand that Hibernate is complaining that it cannot reference a transient instance (ie: `u`), but I cannot persist `u` unless I have an non-null User that I can reference.  But in an empty DB, there is no such entry.

Is this kind of configuration impossible to do?  Or is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying mapping with @ManyToOne ? Also I don't see identifier field, have you omitted it like setters?

Comment: @elusive-code - I updated the entity without the `@Roo` annotations to show the additional files.  Yes - I've left the getters/setters omitted for brevity.  The difference between @ManyToOne and @NotNull, to my understanding, is that the @ManyToOne will be used in the DDL generation and when persisting the bean, however the @NotNull can be used for bean validation even when not persisting the bean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand this Roo annotations and I don't use Hibernate-specific annotations, only JPA. I don't have any issues with self references. But I have some hints fo you:

1. As mentioned before, use `@ManyToOne` annotation.
2. AFAIK, `@NotNull` annotation (or `nullable` field in `@Column`) does not affect mapping, only DDL generation. I don't use DDL generation from domain model, do I never specify this. Instead I use `optional` field of `@ManyToOne`.
3. What identifier generation strategy you use? If autoincrement, self-references are impossible with `NOT NULL` constraint. So either use sequence-based identifier generator or remove constraint. I would use first.
4. As I mentioned, set `optional` field of `@ManyToOne` to `false`, when you have `NOT NULL` constraint. Otherwise Hibernate attempts to make two queries: insert with `createdBy_id` set to `NULL` and then update `createdBy_id`. And the first query fails with `NOT NULL` contraint enabled.

Comment: I've edited the entity to provide example without the `@Roo` annotations.  Yes - I am using autoincrement for this table, had not considered using some other GUID strategy.  I will try a sequence-based identifier.  THe difference between the Hibernate annotation and `@NotNull`, however, to my understanding is that the former will ensure DB schema settings, whereas the latter will work on bean validation even if not persisting to the DB.

Comment: I changed by Auto generation to a Table generation (MySQL does not support sequences).  Now seems to work as desired.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this. You must use a Sequence generator for your ID (instead of the default auto generated IDs).  Then it works.

```
@Entity
public class UserModel {
  /**
   * We must use a sequence for generating IDs,
   * because of the self reference .
   * https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/07/15/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/
   */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", allocationSize = 10)
  private Long id;

  /** reference to a parent user, e.g. the manager */
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  UserModel parentUser;

  [...]
```

The reason is the following: When Hibernate tries to insert a new User it also tries to validate the reference to the parentUser. But that will fail, for the first user we want to insert, or will also fail when a user references himself.

But when IDs are generated with a sequence, then the new/next ID is already known at the time of insert.

Answer (score 0):

The field `createdBy` of `u` can not be null because of the annotation `@NOTNULL`. But `u` referes to itself and its not persist before saving it.
You can set another persisted `User` for `u`, not itself.

Comment: your assumption is right with auto-increment primary key generation. But when using sequence-based PK generator, ID is already known before insertion. So it is really possibly to perform a valid `INSERT` query.

Comment: Like I said in my original post, I knew that is what was causing the problem.  However the question remains - how do you create the first row in the table?  There is no other user to to assign it to.